# How non-SOAP web service clients knows about the structure of the response?

Tags: web-services

How non-SOAP (REST WS, HTTP WS) web service clients knows about the structure of the response?

I mean, is there a **formal** way?

Comment: Can you put it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

The "provider" of the service needs to provide some form of documentation for that service - what parameters are possible, what the response will look like.

This is one of the major drawbacks of non-SOAP services...

There are a few initiatives like `WADL` ([Web Application Description Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Application_Description_Language)) - but those are far from widely accepted and thus not really a valid alternative to WSDL.

Microsoft has also extended REST to include metadata used in WCF REST and the WCF Data Services to allow .NET client-side proxies that "know" about the REST calls and the parameters - but again, that's not really an industry standard that everyone follows.